# Why are all my websites suddenly loaded in desktop mode?

Tags: chrome-for-android

A little while ago my YouTube wasn't working on Chrome on Android tablets, so I hit "Request desktop" and the videos were working fine. But about a month later, Chrome started loading all of my websites in desktop mode, even the search results.

I want all my sites to load in mobile except for YouTube. I don't know why it started happening and I have no idea how to fix it. Please help!

Comment: It's okay if you don't have an idea at first. It's a common occurrence among others as well. But in that case, you should always go to Uncle Web and see if he can [help you](http://lifehacker.com/5824333/a-beginners-guide-to-performing-better-web-searches) with that. He's very kind and he always helps.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using Chrome, tap on the right side menu icon and uncheck Request Desktop Site.